# On reducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials, factorization

Let $f(x),g(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ with $deg(f)>deg(g)$.

Given an integer $B$, is there any algorithm that runs in $\log^c |B|$ for some fixed $c\in \Bbb R$ to find a $h(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ (if one exists) such that:

$(1)$ All coefficients of $h(x)$ are bound by $|B|$,

$(2)$ $deg(f+gh)=deg(f)$ and

$(3)$ $f(x)+g(x)h(x)$ splits in $\Bbb Z[x]$?